# JS Modifying populate contact form dropdown based on URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress

While building a website i tried to use the dynamic Text plugin for CF7 to populate a field based on the previous site.

however, while it displays the desired URL (passed through from offer to contact page "www.webpage.com/contact?offer1" after loading the contactpage, the Dropdown will not display the wanted option.

basically

when on offer page > push "contact now" button > load CF7 with prefiled offer field.

Using Calluna theme and WP 4.9.9

I have tried to use dynamic select extension in wordpress and I have used a shortcode to select but it does not work. It would be perfect to replace it with a "if if else" statement. could something like this work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.contains("?offer1") -1) {
       select("offer1");
    }

    if else(window.location.href.contains("?offer2") -1) {
       select("offer2");
    }    

    if else(window.location.href.contains("?offer3") -1) {
       select("offer2");
    }  

    if else(window.location.href.contains("?offer4") -1) {
       select("offer2");
    }

    else{
       select("Angebote");
    } 

 });
```

Comment: ....so, what is your question then?

Comment: i'm not really sure how to pose the statement...

Answer (score 0):

it is not walid way. Use the following one;

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var matchedData = window.location.href.match(/\?(offer(\d))/);

  if (matchedData) {
    select(matchedData[1]);
    return;
  }

  // default behaviour
   select("Angebote");
 });
```

.. case when you need mapped actions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var matchedData = window.location.href.match(/\?(offer(\d))/);
  var actionsMap = new Map([["offer3", "offer2"], ["offer4", "offer2"]])

  if (matchedData) {
    var actionName = actionsMap.get(matchedData[1]) || matchedData[1];
    select(actionName);
    return;
  }

  // default behaviour
  select("Angebote");
 });
```

Comment: `matchedData` would contain either array of chunks or null. In case of success match then the array will be `["?offer2", "offer2", "2"]` for url where query param contains word `offer2` ans os on.

Comment: in addition if you need to re-map `offer3` for `select("offer2")` then simply use `Map` for that. `var actionsMap = new Map([["offer3", "offer2"], ["offer4", "offer2"]])`.